# No Sound Live USB

Tags: sound, 20.04, spdif

Trying to get sound working on live USB through s/pdif. Thinking about installing 20.04 but, if no sound, no install.

FYI, sound works in latest version of Mint.

Comment: Please try the advice in [this link](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/) and report back.